# Automation Studio "Undefined reference to <Function Block>" compiler error

Tags: plc, br-automation-studio

In Automation Studio a new function block is created.  The compiler gives an error of "Undefined reference to myNewFunctionBlock."  This error message gives no information on how to solve the issue.

How do eliminate this error?

Answer (score 1):

Add the function block to the Software\Library page.

Instructions

1. Open the Configuration View
2. Open Cpu.sw.  This will open the Software page.
3. Expand 'Library Objects'
4. Open the Logical View
5. Drag your function block to 'Library Objects'